# Jenkins pipeline use variable inside shell and curl

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to use a variable inside a curl and shell command, the command is :

```
sh """\ oc exec pod-test -c "conttest" -- \\ /bin/bash -c 'curl X POST \\ -u "usr:pass" \\  -H "content-Type:application/json" \\  -d "{\"id\": \"1\"} \\ http://127.0.0.1:8080/tym/api/obj/$profile/add"' """.stripIndent()
```

the variable profile is not replaced correctly and i have this error : command terminated with exit 3

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you use the right string syntax espacially escaping characters like `"` and `\`.
You can use variables in strings like this
`"${profile}"`

For more information about groovy and strings see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_strings.htm